# angular js: why $scope.product do not update if it is a variable and update if it is a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular js. and I found a problem but I do not know why. can anybody explain that for me? Great thanks.

below is my html file:

```
<div ng-controller="index">
    <input type="text" ng-model="factor" /> {{product}}
</div>
```

below is my js file:

```
angular.module("root", [])
    .controller("index", ["$scope", function($scope) {
        $scope.factor = 6;
        $scope.product = $scope.factor * 2;
    }]);
```

when I change the input to 5, the product value do not update as expected to 10.

but if I changed code like below,the product value update as soon as I change the input

html:

```
<div ng-controller="index">
    <input type="text" ng-model="factor" /> {{product()}}
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module("root", [])
    .controller("index", ["$scope", function($scope) {
        $scope.factor = 6;
        $scope.product = function(){
            return $scope.factor * 2
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: `$scope.product` is just an initialization of the `scope` variable, it is not getting updated every time value changes. In `$scope.product = function`, digestion cycle runs every time value is being changed..

Comment: Better approach would be to use `ng-change` on `input` and update the scope variable..

Comment: @RayonDabre isn't it two way binding if model changes then view should also be updated.

Comment: @Jai, Right! But `$scope.factor` model is being changed. `$scope.product` is never changed. It has not gone through the digest cycle. If you do it like `{{factor*2}}`, it will work as referenced model is updated. Initialized variable will only update if we call a method to update them or it is passed to angular cycle..

Comment: @RayonDabre oh yes! Actually this is the correct answer and should be posted and it removes the dependency on second variable.

Comment: @Jai, he he.. People have shown some efforts, let them get the reward :)

Comment: Why you deselected my answer?

Comment: @Alexander just mis-operating,sorry

Comment: @RayonDabre Can I ask, why $scope.product did not go through the digest cycle. I think the {{expression}} was $watch ed and will go through the digest cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case you initialized the `$scope` fields. And that's it. The field `product` is initialized using the value of the field `factor` but the fields are independent.

In the second case you defined a `$scope` function `product` and its return value is dependent on the `$scope` field `factor` thus any change of `$scope.factor` causes changes of `$scope.product` return value.

Answer (score 0):

When the page is rendered, the product is 12, because 6 * 2 is 12.  Even though you have two-way binding for the factor, but the code to assign factor * 2 to product is not executed again.

As suggested by the comments in, what you should do is set an ng-change event and do $scope.product = $scope.factor * 2;  That should rebind the page if you change the factor.

The reason the product() works is that every time you make a change on the form, functions get executed.  This is very in-effecient, because if you have other fields, the product function still runs, which may not be what you want.

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="index">
    <input type="text" ng-change="factorChanged()" ng-model="factor" /> {{product}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module("root", [])
    .controller("index", ["$scope", function($scope) {
        $scope.factorChanged = function() {
            $scope.product = $scope.factor * 2;
        };

        $scope.factor = 6;
        $scope.factorChanged();
    }]);
```

Comment: Thanking for you answer, in terms of the second case, I think this explain more reasonable
 In $scope.product = function, digestion cycle runs every time value is being changed

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use $watch,please check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pXvU3MevFRmy9VpIdAGL)

```
app
.controller("index", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.factor = 6;
    $scope.$watch('factor',function(newValue,oldValue){
      $scope.product = newValue *2;
    });
}]);
```